# How to access ASP.NET ListView header programmatically?

Tags: c#

I am having a ListView. How do I access the ListView header programmatically?

Comment: ASP.NET? WinForm? ASP.NET? WPF? Silverlight? ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF:

```
var gridView = listView.View as GridView;
gridView.Columns[0].Header = "MyCustomHeader"; //setting header to the first column
```

More info at MSDN [ListView.View property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.view.aspx), [GridView class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx), [GridView.Columns property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.columns.aspx)

Comment: i need this one in ASP.net , not winforms and WPF